# Is There A way to Validate Individual Fields in Jquery, not the Whole Form?

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form.

I applied tabs to it.

I have next and previous links to navigate through the tabs.

I want to validate certain fields on Tab 1, which wen not validated does not allow the user to navigate to the next tab.

I am working with only one form that is divided among the tabs.

The problem is the Jquery Validation Plugin validates the form on submit.

I want to validate individual fields that on click to the Next link.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: just knew how to do it...haha.. so sorry guys:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just saw it on the validation documentation. I almost overlooked it. You do it with

```
$('#myform').validate().element('#myfield_in_myform');
```

whew...